# Converter string para utf-8

Tags: php, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8

Estou precisando transformar uma string na codificação UTF-8. Eu estou declarando ela desse jeito:

```php
$nome = utf8_encode($nome);
```

E mesmo assim não consigo encontrar o erro.

A string aparece desse jeito:

```
ConsolaÃ§Ã£o
```

Comment: Aparece onde? No BD? No browser?

Comment: no browser aparece

Comment: Você verificou se o browser está com a codificação correta? Chrome: Menu->Ferramentas->Codificação->Unicode; Firefox: Alt->View->Encoding (a mesma coisa).

Comment: Se usa texto em português, e está precisando "converter para UTF8" já é indício que algo vai mal: [toda a cadeia de processamento deveria estar rodando em UTF8, sem necessidade de conversões](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8641/4186).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você está tendo problemas no browser, provavelmente está usando encode errado.

Adicione o header `<meta charset="utf-8" />` à seção `head` da sua página, conforme abaixo:

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

De preferência coloque-o no início, de preferência antes da tag `<title>`, que geralmente pode ser alterada pelo usuário, como em uma pesquisa. Falhas de segurança podem ocorrer em navegadores antigos se isso não for seguido ([fonte](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#UTF-7_encoding)).

Comment: No final de 2014 vai ser lançado o HTML5 (!), e este `<meta charset="utf-8" />` é uma novidade do HTML5. Até lá, todavia (e para ambientes legados), convém manter o `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`, que cai ser válido por um bom tempo. Para mais detalhes e surpresas do UTF8 no PHP, [ver essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8641/4186).

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente a conversão deu certo ou foi feita duas vezes. O que pode acontecer é de a página estar sendo mostrada em outra codificação. Experimente colocar

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

no `<head>`da página e veja se aparece corretamente.

Alternativamente, você pode usar `htmlentities()` para exibição, e não depender do encoding para a tela.

```php
$nome_para_display_na_tela = htmlentities($nome);
```

Lembrando que de qualquer forma, vai precisar sempre do encoding certo para a base de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso uma combinação de coisas, por exemplo no php
eu coloco

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",true);
```

e no html dentro das tags head

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: Essa solução (a primeira parte) funciona 100% do tempo.
A segunda parte não é recomendada para html5, onde a meta tag `<meta charset="utf-8" />` é o padrão da especificação.
Não recomendo usar as duas técnicas ou as duas tags na mesma página.

Comment: Muito obrigado @SparK vou parar de utilizar então

Comment: Curiosamente o HTML5 Boilerplate usa as duas técnicas na página deles, o que me leva a concluir que muita gente também.

Comment: O HTML5 vai ser lançado só no final de 2014 (!), até lá, convém manter o `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`, que vai continuar a ser válido por um bom tempo. Para mais detalhes e surpresas do UTF8 no PHP, [ver essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8641/4186).